# I can not get a JSONArrayRequest to work when adding request parameters

Tags: java, android, arrays

I realize that there have been some questions on this already. However, I cannot get this to work. The idea is that I want to make a JSONArrayRequest while also sending request parameters to my server. The error I am getting is the following:

> "Cannot resolve constructor 'JSONArrayRequest....".

Not only that, Android Studio also tells me that annotations are not allowed where I override getParams()

```
 {
 JsonArrayRequest request_json = new 
 JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrlFriends, new 
 Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                }

            });
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams () {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", "Androidhive");
                params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
                params.put("password", "password123");

                return params;
                }

                // Creating RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue requestQueue = 
Volley.newRequestQueue(MyFriendsActivity.this);

                // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
                requestQueue.add(request_json);
            }
        }
```

Is it just not possible to do it this way or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515885/volley-cannot-resolve-constructor-jsonobjectrequest

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parameter JSONArray in JSONArrayRequest , JSONArrayRequest have 5 parameter like this (int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest,Listener listener, ErrorListener errorListener)

Why you dont use StringRequest and in onResponse you can get JSONArray = new JSONArray(response)

Comment: I just changed to StringRequest and converted my response to json array and it worked