# Json parsing not working properly using volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am using volley for parsing. This are the parameters i am passing as post request.

```
{
    "typeName": "MANUFACTURER",
    "typeId": 22,
    "tempId": 308,
    "sortBy": "productname",
    "sortOrder": "desc",
    "filter":[
                {
                    "filterId":101,
                    "typeName":"CAT_ID",

                     "filterId":102,
                    "typeName":"CAT_ID"
                }
             ]
}
```

Now the issue is that if I am adding tempId then I am not getting response. but if i remove tempId I am getting proper response. I check my webservice in postman and other tools. There is no issue with Webservice . Can any one help me to solve this issue? There are no any crash log.

```
 public void Productlistcall()
    {
        showpDialog();


      /* Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jsonParams.put("typeName", "MANUFACTURER");
        jsonParams.put("typeId", "22");
        jsonParams.put("sortBy", "productname");
        jsonParams.put("sortOrder", "desc");*/

        Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

           /* object.put("typeName","MANUFACTURER");
            object.put("typeId","22");
            object.put("tempId","308");
            object.put("sortBy","productname");
            object.put("sortOrder","desc");*/

            if(filter_items!=null)
            {
                jsonParams.put("typeName", "MANUFACTURER");
                jsonParams.put("typeId", "22");
                jsonParams.put("tempId","308");
                jsonParams.put("sortBy", "productname");
                jsonParams.put("sortOrder", "desc");
                JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                String filtersepid = null;
                System.out.println("FILTER LIST DATA IS NOT NULL");
                array.put(obj);
                jsonParams.put("filter",obj.toString());
                for(int i=0;i<filter_items.size();i++)
                {
                    filtersepid=filter_items.get(i);
                    System.out.println("filtersepid"+filtersepid);
                    try {
                        obj.put("filterId",filter_items.get(i));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        obj.put("typeName","CAT_ID");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                jsonParams.put("typeName", "MANUFACTURER");
                jsonParams.put("typeId", "22");
                jsonParams.put("tempId","308");
                jsonParams.put("sortBy", "productname");
                jsonParams.put("sortOrder", "desc");
                System.out.println("FILTER LIST DATA IS NULL");
            }

        System.out.println("DRAWER PARAMS" + jsonParams);
        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, url,

                new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        System.out.println("response Productlist-->> " + response.toString());

                        productlist = new ArrayList<ProductListModel>();

                        ch_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        color_list=new ArrayList<String>();

                        try {
                            JSONObject drawerdatas = (JSONObject) response.getJSONObject("Data");

                            JSONArray products=drawerdatas.getJSONArray("products");
                            JSONArray filtersdata=drawerdatas.getJSONArray("filtersList");
                            JSONArray sortingdata=drawerdatas.getJSONArray("sortingList");

                            String headerText=drawerdatas.getString("headerText");
                            String productCount=drawerdatas.getString("productCount");

                            productlist = new ArrayList<ProductListModel>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < products.length(); j++) {

                                JSONObject jo = products.getJSONObject(j);

                                ProductListModel ch = new ProductListModel();
                                ch.setProduct_Id(jo.getString("productId"));
                                ch.setProduct_Name(jo.getString("productName"));
                                ch.setProduct_Img(jo.getString("productImage"));
                                ch.setProduct_Price(jo.getString("productSP"));
                                ch.setProduct_RatingImgPath(jo.getString("productRatingImage"));
                                ch.setProduct_pRating(jo.getString("productRatingCount"));


                             /*   if(jo.getString("productOfferText").equals("null"))
                                {
                                    ch_list.add(" ");
                                    System.out.println("text is null");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    JSONArray txtdetail=jo.getJSONArray("productOfferText");
                                    System.out.println("txtdetailarray"+txtdetail);
                                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                    for(int k=0;k<txtdetail.length();k++)
                                    {
                                        JSONObject jdetail=txtdetail.getJSONObject(k);
                                        disptext=jdetail.getString("displayText");
                                        dispclr=jdetail.getString("displayColor");
                                        //ch_list.add(disptext);
                                        color_list.add(dispclr);
                                        // sb.append(disptext);
                                        System.out.println("clr" + color_list.get(k).toString());
                                        colors=color_list.get(k);
                                        String string = colors;
                                        String[] parts = string.split("\\*");
                                        int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                                        int part2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                                        int part3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                                        hex = String.format("#%02X%02X%02X", part1, part2, part3);
                                        sb.append(addColor(disptext.trim(), hex));
                                        System.out.println("hexa"+hex);

                                    }

                                    detailtext=sb.toString();
                                    ch_list.add(detailtext);
                                    System.out.println("Output: " + sb.toString().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n"));
                                }
*/
                                productlist.add(ch);
                            }

                           filterlist = new ArrayList<ModelUser>();



                            for(int c=0;c<filtersdata.length();c++)
                            {
                                JSONObject jo = filtersdata.getJSONObject(c);
                                JSONArray filters=jo.getJSONArray("filters");
                                String groupName=jo.getString("groupName");
                                String typeName=jo.getString("typeName");

                                for(int g=0;g<filters.length();g++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject jos = filters.getJSONObject(g);
                                    ModelUser flm = new ModelUser();
                                    flm.setId(Integer.parseInt(jos.getString("filterId")));
                                    flm.setUserName(jos.getString("filterName"));
                                    filterlist.add(flm);
                                }

                            }
                            sortlist=new ArrayList<SortingListModel>();
                            for(int d=0;d<sortingdata.length();d++)
                            {
                                JSONObject jo = sortingdata.getJSONObject(d);
                                SortingListModel scm = new SortingListModel();
                                scm.setSort_text(jo.getString("text"));
                                scm.setSort_value(jo.getString("value"));
                                sortlist.add(scm);
                            }

                            rvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),productlist);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

                            pronames.setText(headerText);
                            if(productlist.size() < 2)
                            {
                                procounts.setText(String.valueOf(productlist.size() + " Product"));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                procounts.setText(String.valueOf(productlist.size() + " Products"));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Handle Error
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("API_Version","1.0");
                headers.put("deviceName","ANDROID");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(postRequest);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this

jsonParams.put("tempId","308");

Try this

jsonParams.put("cityId","308");

Comment: yes you are right. but i created tempID for testing to check whether it work or not.. but neither cityID not tempId work for me..check updated question..its just word mistakes in my question

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange and use below code in the if else  condition.  You are not generating json in right order

```
if(filter_items!=null)
            {
                jsonParams.put("typeName", "MANUFACTURER");
                jsonParams.put("typeId", "22");
                jsonParams.put("tempId","308");
                jsonParams.put("sortBy", "productname");
                jsonParams.put("sortOrder", "desc");
                JSONArray array=new JSONArray();                 
                String filtersepid = null;
                System.out.println("FILTER LIST DATA IS NOT NULL");


                for(int i=0;i<filter_items.size();i++)
                { 
                    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                    filtersepid=filter_items.get(i);
                    System.out.println("filtersepid"+filtersepid);
                    try {
                        obj.put("filterId",filter_items.get(i));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        obj.put("typeName","CAT_ID");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  array.put(obj);
                }
            jsonParams.put("filter",array);
            }
            else
            {
                jsonParams.put("typeName", "MANUFACTURER");
                jsonParams.put("typeId", "22");
                jsonParams.put("tempId","308");
                jsonParams.put("sortBy", "productname");
                jsonParams.put("sortOrder", "desc");
                System.out.println("FILTER LIST DATA IS NULL");
            }
```

Comment: showing red line here

jsonParams.put("filter",array);

Comment: Use JSONObject jsonParams= new JSONObject() for initializing jsonParams. remove map

Comment: it shows can not resolve constructor error

  JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, urls,

                new JSONObject(jsonParams),

Comment: i change it as per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558238/4817574

Now its showing this error

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value  at Data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Could you please post full stack trace in your question

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the use of

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

I was using this one

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```