# Volley JsonObjectRequest not fetching data

Tags: android, json, constructor, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am trying to work on  volley with gridview. JsonObjectRequest does not fetch any response. I looked up for links on stackoverflow abt JsonObjectRequest passing null as parameter and changing volley version but nothing works as the error was Volley - Cannot Resolve Constructor "JSONObjectRequest. Now no error but no  response also.  Any help appreciated! Below example link : http://hemanthsomaraju.blogspot.com/2019/03/android-grid-view-using-volley-api.html and volley version: implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'. Links referred: [Volley - Cannot Resolve Constructor "JSONObjectRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515885/volley-cannot-resolve-constructor-jsonobjectrequest)

```
public class OutputActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView ListView;
VolleyListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<CommonBean> VolleyList = new ArrayList<CommonBean>();
private ProgressDialog mprocessingdialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_output);
    ListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    adapter = new VolleyListViewAdapter(OutputActivity.this, VolleyList);
    ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    new OutputActivity.GetListAsync().execute();
}
private class GetListAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        mprocessingdialog = new ProgressDialog(OutputActivity.this);
        mprocessingdialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        mprocessingdialog.setMessage("Loading");
        mprocessingdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mprocessingdialog.setCancelable(false);
        mprocessingdialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "https://api.fnpplus.com/productapi/api/rest/v1.2/productList?catalogId=india",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("rlog", response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("productResults");
                            Log.d("rlog", jsonArray.toString());
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                CommonBean commonBean = new CommonBean();
                                commonBean.setTextView1(obj.optString("productName"));
                                JSONObject jsonObject2 = obj.getJSONObject("price");
                                Log.d("rlog1", jsonObject2.toString());
                                commonBean.setTextView2(jsonObject2.optString("price"));
                                Log.d("rlog12", jsonObject2.optString("price"));
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = obj.getJSONObject("productImage");
                                Log.d("rlog1", jsonObject1.toString());
                                commonBean.setImageView(jsonObject1.optString("path"));
                                Log.d("rlog12", jsonObject1.optString("path"));
                                VolleyList.add(commonBean);
                            }
                            mprocessingdialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("rlog", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(OutputActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mprocessingdialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, 30000);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you declared internet access permission in your manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the **StringRequest** and add your data as per your expected conditions

No Need to use **AsyncTask** and you can add loader in code also.

```
 RequestQueue queue;
        String URL = "https://api.fnpplus.com/productapi/api/rest/v1.2/productList?catalogId=india";
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject dataJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = dataJsonObject.getJSONArray("productResults");
                    Log.d("rlog", jsonArray.toString());
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("error", error.toString());
            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        queue.add(request);
}
```